# Socket.io limit packets numbers

Tags: node.js, socket.io, html5-filesystem

I'm working actually on a file transfer system using socket.io and HTML5 file API.
https://github.com/xblaster/Nodjawnloader (stable branch)

The main problem I have is for huge file. Socket.io send me all packets in one huge transfer chunk and the Google Chrome javascript VM just crash when it receive around 70MB of packets.

Can I limit socket.io chunks for xhr-poll or jsonp calls ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a mechanism for limiting the packet size on XHR or JSONP, but there is nothing stopping you from splitting up the file yourself and sending chunks. Then you can reassemble on the client side.